# how to use the images that have been create by "Offload rbd’s copy_volume_to_image" method in openstack?

Tags: openstack, ceph

I have an openstack integrated with ceph.
I'm working on the fastest way to create a copy of an instance's volume without using cinder_backup module.
in the Ceph it is possible to access the rbd files that are stored in the pool (like volume pools), We can export them and then create an image from it and create another instance.
but also there is another method named " Offload rbd’s copy_volume_to_image" https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/cinder-specs/specs/liberty/optimze-rbd-copy-volume-to-image.html
I wonder how I can use these copied volumes to image pools in the Openstack because after doing this the images are in the rbd pool but not usable in the OpenStack because the OpenStack hasn't generated it and doesn't have an OpenStack ID.
I wonder if you could help me to know how I can use images after creating with this method.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cinder to manage existing rbd images and "adopt" them into openstack. Assuming you already cloned or copied the source image to your target image (for example: `rbd clone fast-pool/image@snap fast-pool/new_image`), you need the backend information, here's an example from one of our clusters (we use two different rbd pools for fast and slow storage):

```
control01:~ # cinder get-pools
+----------+---------------------+
| Property | Value               |
+----------+---------------------+
| name     | control@rbd#rbd-ssd |
+----------+---------------------+
+----------+----------------------+
| Property | Value                |
+----------+----------------------+
| name     | control@rbd2#rbd-hdd |
+----------+----------------------+
```

The target image I wanted to manage is in the fast storage (rbd-ssd), so this is the command I need to let cinder manage it as a volume and make it "known by openstack":

```
cinder manage --name new_volume_name control@rbd#rbd-ssd new_image
```

"new_volume_name" is the name which you will then see in the `cinder list` output, while "new_image" is the cloned rbd image you create in the previous step.

Answer (score -1):

@eblock thanks for your reply.
I have a different situation here. I already have my cloned images on one of my pools named images. but the cinder sees different pools than the pools in the ceph. here are my pools in the ceph

```
# ceph osd pool ls 
.mgr
images
volumes
backup
```

and here is what Cinder sees:

```
# cinder get-pools
+----------+-------------------------+
| Property | Value                   |
+----------+-------------------------+
| name     | controller3@rbd-1#rbd-1 |
+----------+-------------------------+
+----------+-------------------------+
| Property | Value                   |
+----------+-------------------------+
| name     | controller2@rbd-1#rbd-1 |
+----------+-------------------------+
+----------+-------------------------+
| Property | Value                   |
+----------+-------------------------+
| name     | controller1@rbd-1#rbd-1 |
+----------+-------------------------+
```

so when I try to use the "cinder manage" command,

```
cinder manage --name  my_new_volume  controller1@rbd-1#rbd-1  my_cloned_image
```

it creates the volume and stuck in "error" status, Also I get this error in the cinder log file:

```
cinder.exception.ManageExistingInvalidReference: Manage existing volume failed due to invalid backend reference my_cloned_image: Specified rbd image does not exist.
```

i even change the backend address to pools name in the ceph but didn't helped.

Comment: Your comment is not an answer, you should edit your question and add that information there. Anyway, the cloned image needs to be in the pool cinder has access to, so you should clone it to your cinder pool ("volumes") and then manage it via cinder.

Comment: @eblock Thank you so much. it worked perfectly. also thanks for your hint about the comment and answer, I am afraid if I delete my "wrong" answer your comment will be deleted too.